# Perform "SET NAMES" using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I perform this instruction using PDO?

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Here is what I tried, but it fails:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SET NAMES 'utf8'); $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: look at the comment !

Comment: No it must be `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); $stmt->execute();`

Comment: Your quotes are wrong, ask question properly, help others when they try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```